# Centos 6 libCurl TLSv1 Error

Tags: curl, openssl, centos

I have a php script that hits an https url to grab data. I was on Centos 5 prior and this script didn't show any issues. However, after switching to Centos 6 the script stopped working and the error I keep getting is `Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1.`

In the php script I am forcing TLSv1:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

I'm not sure what's causing this to happen. Current Curl version is

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL lib
```

OpenSSL Version:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On CentOS 5 curl was built against OpenSSL.

On CentOS 6 curl is built against NSS.

They do not support the same cipher list strings. That being said I couldn't, in the short time I had to try it, get any cipher strings to work with curl+NSS.

Also, don't expect to be able to use custom certificate stores for root certificates/etc. with curl+NSS... you can't.

Comment: Okay so that makes sense because I was searching around I saw that there are curl-openssl packages. Would you recommend replacing the NSS curl with the openssl? I did try to install it but looks like they are sitting side by side and I can't seem to replace one with the other.

Comment: @foureight84 Where did you find this `curl-openssl` package? And I don't know that you can replace the one that yum/pycurl is using.

Comment: http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=security%3Ashibboleth&package=curl-openssl there is also a libcurl-openssl

Comment: In general "random" repositories aren't a good idea. I wouldn't worry about quality from that repository like I would for many others but it probably wasn't designed for use on arbitrary CentOS systems.

Comment: Yeah, those packages are quite purpose-built for shibboleth (as can be seen by the path they install under).

Comment: got it. Thank you for demystifying the issue